# Update an history using Python

Tags: python, list, copy

I'm programming a chess game and want to include an history of the game.

There is a big class Chess, a smaller class ChessManager, that has the attribute chess_board. The history is an attribute of ChessManager.

Here is the code

```
class Chess : 

[...]

def upload_history(self):
local_board = self.ChessManager.chess_board.copy()
self.ChessManger.history.append(local_board)
```

However, when a move is made, all entries of history are just a copy of the last move. How could I fix the problem? I tried many variations but it didn't work.

I made a "toy version" of the problem where the outcome is as expected :

```
class ClassTest:
    def __init__(self,list,turn,history):
        self.list = list 
        self.turn = turn 
        self.history = history
    

myClass = ClassTest(list = [], turn = 0, history = [])

for i in range(10): 
    myClass.turn = i 
    local_list = myClass.list.copy()
    local_list.append(myClass.turn)
    myClass.list = local_list
    myClass.history.append(myClass.list)

print(myClass.history)
```

but this toy code doesn't work in my original chess code.

Comment: When I replicate this code in my python interpreter I get the following: ```[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]```, which seems to me like the history of the game. Is there other code affecting the history attribute?

Comment: @Lawrence : Exactly, but it's the toy example. In the real example, it's the only line where I use the history (except to print it or to compare it but it should be fine). Does the first code looks fine to you?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by big class and small class.? Do you mean parent class? 
2. If history is attribute of class Chess, then why are you writing 
 "self.ChessManger.history.append(local_board)" ? 
3. Also, you should provide a code that has error so that it can be debugged.

Comment: @VidyaMarathe : 1 : yes I meant parent class. 2 history is attribute of ChessManager, I'll edit it. 3 the original code is very long and I don't want to share it yet. I was hoping there could be a simple solution, otherwise I can think about it more.